# Python waits for typing

Tags: python

Im just 14 and pretty new to python. I want to make my program to wait for the user to type something (for example yes or no) and then react different depending on the answer. Im using Python 3 (3.4). Are there any simple ways to do this?

Comment: `input('Write something')`. Also, read the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: Did you read a python tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`input()` function](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input):

```
choice = input("Enter Yes or No: ")
```

But I would recomment you to read a book or [Python tutorials](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/) first, which covers all you need to know to start in Python.

Comment: I think it should be [`raw input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) and not [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: In *Python 3.x* [`raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answers and comments, I would strongly suggest going through a Python tutorial.

But in answer to your question about getting user input and branching:

```
user_choice = input("Enter yes or no: ")
if user_choice == "yes":
    print("User entered 'yes'!")
elif user_choice == "no":
    print("User entered 'no'!")
else:
    print("Unknown value entered.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `input()` function. You should store it in a variable if you'd like to use the input later this way:

```
varname = input()
```

Or:

```
varname = input('Write your message here')
```

You'd better go through a python tutorial, check:
[Invent With Python](http://inventwithpython.com/chapters/)
[Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)
[Code Academy, Python](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python)